# How to set categoryGroupVisibilities in Permissionset XML for Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

I'm trying to transition some of my Profile settings to Permission Sets to make them reusable. Trying to set the Knowledge Data Category access in the Permission Set. I can do it through the UI but not through the XML. This means I can't pass the configuration change through source control which is necessary.

Profile manages this through the `categoryGroupVisibilities` element but that doesn't seem to work for Permission Sets.
Profile: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm

Permission Set: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm

Am I missing some other kind of junction type or other metadata I should be able to manage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Winter 19 added the categoryGroupVisibilities field to Profiles but not to Permission Sets. See the Winter 19 Release Notes below. This will likely be fixed in a future version of the Metadata API.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm

Comment: Will update this when the feature is available.